# Jump to matching XML tags in Vim

Tags: xml, vim

Vim `%` operator jumps to matching parentheses, comment ends and a few other things.  It doesn't, however, match XML tags (or any other tag, to the best of my knowledge).

What's the best way to jump to the matching XML tag using Vim?

**Note:**  What I *really* want to do is duplicate a section in an XML file without manually looking for the matching tag.

Comment: In addressing the original question (preceding the clarifying **Note:**), the [v + a + t combination](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10881471/921836) seems to drop you to the bottom of the visual selection. The other side of this seems to be the "o" command within the visual mode, which takes you to the alternate end of your current selection. This is an effective trick not only in XML documents, but also when editing PHP/HTML (as happened to be the case for myself).

Comment: Related: [How to jump between matching HTML/XML tags?](http://vi.stackexchange.com/q/780/467) at Vim SE

Answer (score 75, accepted):

There is a vim plugin called matchit.vim . You can find it here: http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=39 . It was created pretty much the exact purpose you describe.

Install that, place your cursor on the body of the tag (not the <>, else it'll match those) and press % to jump to the other tag. See the script's page to find out what else it matches.

Comment: Nice one. Has been sitting on my hard disk all the time.

Comment: There's some version of matchit, which ships with Vim already btw. `runtime macros/matchit.vim` should enable it, and allow `%` to match XML tags.

Comment: mtchit.vim appears to be enabled by default in NeoVim.

Comment: It might be you already have matchit, but is not enabled by default. Add `packadd! matchit` to `.vimrc` to enable it. Read more `:help matchit`

Comment: `matchit` fails in a large html source.
https://github.com/andymass/vim-matchup succeeds in the source.

Answer (score 261):

You can do this without additional plugins:

- place cursor on the tag
- <kbd>v</kbd><kbd>a</kbd><kbd>t</kbd> - will select the (outer) tag and place cursor on the end
- once you've got your selection you can toggle between the top and bottom with <kbd>o</kbd> (*update based on Michael Gruber's note*)
- <kbd>c</kbd> - change or, <kbd>y</kbd> - copy or, escape for leaving visual mode ...

Another useful operation is: <kbd>v</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>t</kbd> - will select content of the tag (inner).

**Update (thanks to @elrado)** Example: <kbd>v</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>t</kbd><kbd>o</kbd> will enable you to select inner content of the tag and position cursor on the beginning of the selected text.

Reference: https://superuser.com/questions/182355/how-can-i-select-an-html-tags-content-in-vim

Vim reference (thanks to @Geek for noting this out):

```
:help visual-operators
```

you'll get:

```
4. Operating on the Visual area             *visual-operators*

The objects that can be used are:
    ...
    at  a <tag> </tag> block (with tags)        |v_at|
    it  inner <tag> </tag> block            |v_it|
    ...
```

Comment: I want to jump to a tag, not "select" the enclosed content.
And if i can do it with 1 or 2 key strokes, why will I do 5 key-presses every time I want to select a tag? (which happens a LOT of times actually)

Comment: Nice that there's a built-in way, albeit a convoluted one, to jump to the closing tag. Is taking a detour through visual mode the only way of getting there?

Comment: Holy molly, you always learn new things with Vim! There's so much to learn, this helped me a lot, thanks!

Comment: Just to note: once you've got your selection you can toggle between the top and bottom with 'o'

Comment: @Robert for the second bullet point what does the combination `a+t` stand for? Like `c` stands for *copy* and `y` stands for *yank*. It is much easier to memorize when you understand what a particular combination stands for.

Comment: Thanks for noting this out. I have updated the answer (hope this clears things up).

Comment: @Geek, 't' is for 'tag'. To understand 'a' you must first understand 'i'. `cit` changes the **i**nterior of the tag - just the content. `cat` change **a**ll of the tag - the contents and **a**lso the tag itself, both opening and closing.

Comment: Came here looking for this, found it. Brilliant!

Comment: @kumar_harsh you can do it with one key. You just add a mapping in your .vimrc to `vat<Esc>` and it'll be one key. There is no reason to use a plugin to give you one mapping!!

Comment: Funny thing is that I am using ci} or ci> or ci) all the time, but never thaught to use vit+o. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: vito<esc> is easier for me than shift+5 - and I like that it's built in!

Comment: What is the meaning of  `o` in the visual mode?

Comment: @foxiris `:h v_o` (or, help for `o` in `visual` mode).

Can't say it better than vim help does
"Go to Other end of highlighted text ..."

Comment: Thank you, now I know how to use the help command for visual mode `v_`

Answer (score 37):

The OP stated that what he really wanted to do is copy a section of XML without having to find the matching tag.  This is easily done in normal mode with `yat<motion>p`, which yanks the text inside and including the matching tags, then pastes it.  `yit<motion>p` is almost the same, but it doesn't include the outer tags.

The 'y' in the string is of course the normal mode "yank" command.  (`:help y`)

`a` or `i` can be used for object selection after an operator such as `y` or inside a visual selection.  The symbol after `a` or `i` specifies what should be selected.  The object type `t` used here indicates an SGML tag.  (`:help object-select`).

Of course `<motion>` just means to move somewhere by the means of your choice and `p` puts the yanked text at that location.

Comment: `i` stands for "inside" (or "inner"). `a` stands for "a"?

Comment: @nilon `a` stands for "all".

Comment: The mnemonic I use is that `a` stands for *around*. It makes more sense to me.

Answer (score 6):

Just my trick of using "yank", "object-select" (tag select) and "jump to last yanked text".

```
yit`]
```

to jump to right before closing tag

and

```
yit
```

to jump to right after opening tag

Note: this will change the content of default register