# Commenting out XML in vim

Tags: vim

I often find myself removing and adding XML sections in configuration files:

- tomcat's server.xml
- maven's settings.xml

and many others.

Is there a vim plugin/command to make this simple?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use a combination of matching XML tags, as can be seen in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500989/jump-to-matching-xml-tags-in-vim) and Perl's search and replace.

For instance, given this snippet:

```
<TypeDef name="a">
  <ArrayType high="14" low="0">
    <UndefType type="node">
    </UndefType>
  </ArrayType>
</TypeDef>
```

Put the cursor on either the opening or closing `TypeDef` and type the following sequence:

```
vat:s/^\(.*\)$/<!--\1-->/
```

`v` - puts you into visual mode
`at` - selects the whole XML tag
`:s/^\(.*\)$/<!--\1-->/` - surrounds each line with `'<!--...-->'`, the comment delimiters for XML

Alternatively, you can just delete it like this:

```
dat
```

`d` - delete according to the following movements
`at` - as before

Comment: Your update is very insightful.

I can then use vat:s/-->// to delete comments.

Thank you.

Comment: +1 for the `dat` information.  Should get even more if you show how to add this to a hotkey.

Comment: @MerlynMorgan-Graham Do you mean something like: `nmap <leader>dt dat`

Comment: Can I only add one pair of comment delimiter at the beginning and end of XML tag? How can I quickly uncomment the XML tag?

Answer (score 6):

use [surround.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1697) for general tag matching, deleting, inserting, surrounding etc,

For commenting tags, it is easy to use vim text objects & and a simple macro

Example:

enter

```
vmap ,c <esc>a--><esc>'<i<!--<esc>'>$
```

somewhere suitable, then place your cursor at the capital "A" of "ArrayType" on line two of the following (borrowed from Nathan Fellmans example above)

```
<TypeDef name="a">
  <ArrayType high="14" low="0">
    <UndefType type="node">
    </UndefType>
  </ArrayType>
</TypeDef>
```

then hit

```
vat,c
```

and you will get:

```
<TypeDef name="a">
  <!--<ArrayType high="14" low="0">
    <UndefType type="node">
    </UndefType>
  </ArrayType>-->
</TypeDef>
```

with your cursor at the end of the comment

Answer (score 6):

I love the simplicity of https://github.com/tpope/vim-commentary. Easy to add other languages, though seems to support most out of the box. Under 100 lines of code.

`gcc` to comment the current line, or select the text you want to comment and hit `gc`. Super easy.

Comment: "Super easy" is an understatement if you have bundle set up.  I hope more people find this one.

Answer (score 5):

Vim doesn't have smart commenting for all file types by itself. You should get a script for your commenting needs.

I use the enhcomentify script which has been around and maintained for a long time

http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=23

It seems to do xml well and you get the advantage of the same key bindings for any filetype you are using.

There are others.. notably the NERD Commenter

http://www.vim.org/scripts/script_search_results.php?keywords=comment&script_type=&order_by=rating&direction=descending&search=search

Comment: EnhCommentify seems to be dead (last update in 2008) but NERD Commenter is still under active development and is working well for me.

Comment: @luator This answer is old indeed. I use vim-commentary now.

Answer (score 2):

I think that adapting [this vim tip](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Wrap_a_visual_selection_in_an_HTML_tag) might be useful.

I propose adding:

```
" Wrap visual selection in an XML comment
vmap <Leader>c <Esc>:call CommentWrap()<CR>
function! CommentWrap()
  normal `>
  if &selection == 'exclusive'
    exe "normal i-->"
  else
    exe "normal a-->"
  endif
  normal `<
  exe "normal i<!--"
  normal `<
endfunction
```

to your .vimrc

Then, with a visual selection active (V), hit \c (backslash then c) to wrap your block in `<!-- -->` XML-style comments.

Alternatively, as suggested on the wiki you can put the code in ~/.vim/scripts/wrapwithcomment.vim and add to your .vimrc:

```
au Filetype html,xml source ~/.vim/scripts/wrapwithcomment.vim
```

to only load that functionality when working on a html or xml file.

Answer (score 1):

Best it'd be if you'd find a command that adds things in the beginning and end of the selection.

When I'm commenting python code, I'm doing this:

```
:2,4s/^/#/g
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it does point me in the right direction. But how would  I go about appending '<!--' to the first row and prepeding '-->' to the last one?

Comment: vim macros make this easy, by either using the '< and '> marks that go with visual selections, or moving the cursor from one end of the visual selection to the other with "o"