# How to comment out HTML/XML element in VIM?

Tags: html, xml, vim, editor

What's the best shortcut or plugin to comment out HTML/XML elements?

And also need to uncomment.

Answer (score 8):

You can use a combination of matching XML tags, as can be seen in this question and Perl's search and replace.

For instance, given this snippet:

```
<TypeDef name="a">
  <ArrayType high="14" low="0">
    <UndefType type="node">
    </UndefType>
  </ArrayType>
</TypeDef>
```

Put the cursor on either the opening or closing TypeDef and type the following sequence:

```
vat:s/^\(.*\)$/<!-- \1 -->/
```

1. `v` - puts you into visual mode
2. `at` - selects the whole XML tag
3. `:s/^\(.*\)$/<!-- \1 -->/` - surrounds each line with `'<!-- ... -->'`, the comment delimiters for XML

Alternatively, you can just delete it like this:

```
dat
```

1. `d` - delete according to the following movements
2. `at` - as before

To delete id use  then use `vat:s/-->//` to delete comments

Comment: In case someone wondered, you'll also need to do vat:s/<!--// to delete the start of the comments in each line or select it visually with Ctrl+v and delete them with x. For all the commands mentioned, you can also copy what's after the : into the clipboard and paste it in command mode with Ctrl+r + or Ctrl+r *.

Comment: Also, do :nohl to clear the highlighting (or remap this :let @/ = ""<CR> from https://stackoverflow.com/q/657447/18115206).

Comment: Another way to uncomment (modified from vi.stackexchange.com/a/17777/31302): vat:norm!05x$4X

Comment: You forgot to attribute the original author of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/934065/18115206), Nathan Fellman

Answer (score 6):

I use the [tComment](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1173) plugin. You can find a detailed video tutorial [here](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/other/vim-essential-plugin-tcomment/) on how to install and use it.

The plugin is very useful as it allows you to toggle comments from both the command and input interface, and you can do so using both visual mode and motions (like `gcw`, or `gc3w`)

Comment: Thanks, I tried out tComment and am pretty happy with it. Check out http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/other/vim-essential-plugin-tcomment/ on how to get started.

Answer (score 3):

If you use [emmet-vim](https://github.com/mattn/emmet-vim), you can select the whole contents of the tag you would like to comment out by pressing `v a t` and then press `Ctrl y /`

Answer (score 1):

To comment: `vato<ESC>i<!-- <ESC>vatA --><ESC>`

1. Position the cursor anywhere inside the HTML block. Not inside a nested one unless you want to comment that one.
2. [Go to the opening tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6270396/navigating-html-tags-in-vim): `vato`
3. Exit visual mode: `Esc`
4. Insert: `i<!--`
5. Exit insert mode: `Esc`
6. Go to closing tag: `vat`
7. Append: `A -->`
8. Exit insert mode: `Esc`

Note: You may use `I` to insert directly from visual mode, and it'll work with multi-line blocks, but for single line elements it'll mess up the indentation.

---

To uncomment: `vat<ESC>4xvato<Esc>5X`

1. Position the cursor anywhere inside the HTML block, ending comment delimiter excluded.
2. Go to the closing tag: `vat`
3. Exit visual mode: `Esc`
4. Delete 4 chars: `4x`
5. Go to the opening tag `vato`
6. Delete preceding 5 chars: `5X`

---

### Using .vimrc or init.vim to create shorcuts

You may add these lines to [your .vimrc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10921441/where-is-my-vimrc-file) (or init.vim in neovim) to [remap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3776117/what-is-the-difference-between-the-remap-noremap-nnoremap-and-vnoremap-mapping) shortcuts:

```
" Comment HTML element
nnoremap <silent> <leader>h :set lazyredraw<cr>mhvato<ESC>i<!-- <ESC>vatA --><ESC>`h:set nolazyredraw<cr>

" Uncomment HTML element
nnoremap <silent> <leader>H :set lazyredraw<cr>mhvat<ESC>4xvato<ESC>5X`h:set nolazyredraw<cr>
```

**Warning:**

- You will need to `u`ndo if you try to uncomment a non-commented area for it will delete some characters. You could avoid this by replacing `4x` with `d2f-` and `5X` with `dF!`, but then you'd have issues with [this kind of workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1097006/removing-whitespace-between-html-elements-when-using-line-breaks/1097063#1097063) and anything else in the same line that contains -...- or !.
- If there are already comments in between the tags of the element to comment out, you will need to uncomment those first.

Notes:

- Change `<leader>h` and `<leader>H` to what you'd like to use.
- `:set lazyredraw` is to [hide intermediate steps](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/9776/ability-to-make-vim-run-commands-in-background-and-only-show-the-final-result-on) by not redrawing the screen and `:set nolazyredraw` to avoid possible visual glitches afterwards.
- `mh` is to [save current cursor position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27193867/vim-how-can-i-put-my-current-position-in-jumplist/27194580#27194580) and `` `h `` is to jump back to that line and column. You may replace h with [any other lower case letter](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Using_marks).

Tip: Use [:source $MYVIMRC](https://superuser.com/questions/132029/how-do-you-reload-your-vimrc-file-without-restarting-vim) to apply changes done to .vimrc (or init.vim) without having to restart vim.