# How can I find the closing HTML tag quickly in Vim?

Tags: html, vim

Just like editing C source files, I can press <kbd>%</kbd> to get the closing `}` for the current cursor's `{`.

How can I do this when editing HTML files? Are there any shortcuts?

To be clear, I want:

```
<html>
</html>
```

When the cursor moves to `<html>`, I want to press a key so that the cursor will jump to `</html>`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jump to matching XML tags in Vim](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500989/jump-to-matching-xml-tags-in-vim)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You should be able to do this with the matchit plugin by typing % when your mouse is on the opening tag.

http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=39

Comment: If I am not mistaken, matchit plugin is included into vim distro, so this link is irrelevant. To install it, see `:h matchit-install` (but I suggest you to replace all `cp` commands with `ln -s`, in order not to recopy matchit every time it is updated).

Comment: Depends on your distro. It seems gvimportable from portableapps.com does not include it. I might be mistaken and I hope so.

Answer (score 27):

You can jump between tags using visual operators, in example:

1. Place the cursor on the tag.
2. Enter visual mode by pressing <kbd>v</kbd>.
3. Select the outer tag block by pressing <kbd>a</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> or <kbd>i</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> for inner tag block.

Your cursor should jump forward to the matching closing html/xml tag. To jump backwards from closing tag, press <kbd>o</kbd> or <kbd>O</kbd> to jump to opposite tag.

Now you can either exit visual by pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd>, change it by <kbd>c</kbd> or copy by <kbd>y</kbd>.

---

To record that action into register, press <kbd>qq</kbd> to start recording, perform tag jump as above (including <kbd>Esc</kbd>), press <kbd>q</kbd> to finish. Then to invoke jump, press <kbd>@q</kbd>.

---

See more help at `:help visual-operators` or `:help v_it`:

> <kbd>at</kbd>      a `<tag> </tag>` block (with tags)
>
> <kbd>it</kbd>      inner `<tag> </tag>` block

---

Alternatively use plugin such as [matchit.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=39) (See: [Using % in languages without curly braces](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/126/using-in-languages-without-curly-braces)).

---

See also:

- [How to jump between matching HTML/XML tags?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/780/467) at Vim SE
- [Jump to matching XML tags in Vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500989/jump-to-matching-xml-tags-in-vim) at stackoverflow SE
- [Navigating HTML tags in Vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6270396/navigating-html-tags-in-vim) at stackoverflow SE
- [How to navigate between begin and end html tag?](https://superuser.com/questions/189815/vim-how-to-navigate-between-begin-and-end-html-tag) at superuser SE
- [VIM jump from one xml tag to the closing one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38187/vim-jump-from-one-xml-tag-to-the-closing-one) at Unix SE
- [How can I select an html tag's content in Vim?](https://superuser.com/questions/182355/how-can-i-select-an-html-tags-content-in-vim) at superuser SE

Comment: Outstanding. I had been looking for something to parse HTML and find beginning and end tags, but could find nothing useful. HTML is a jumbled mess at the best of times. The worst of all markups, and no markup is good. This worked well, thanks.

Comment: huge +1 for this: Your cursor should jump forward to the matching closing html/xml tag. To jump backwards from closing tag, press o or O to jump to opposite tag. 

Never knew that. Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 6):

I have had problems with this is the past, even with the matchit plugin. The way I solved it was to modify b:match_words on xml-type files. Here is the relevant section from my .vimrc:

```
  autocmd FileType html let b:match_words = '<\(\w\w*\):</\1,{:}'
  autocmd FileType xhtml let b:match_words = '<\(\w\w*\):</\1,{:}'
  autocmd FileType xml let b:match_words = '<\(\w\w*\):</\1,{:}'
```

Try it out, see if it helps any.

Comment: You may have a line in your `.vimrc` :  `:let loaded_matchit = 1`. I added it at beginning without read the doc carefully. So it make me spends a lot of time debugging this error.

Comment: In my case I don't have this line, but thank you for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

MatchTagAlways is a plugin that always highlights the XML/HTML tags that enclose your cursor location.

https://github.com/Valloric/MatchTagAlways

Answer (score 0):

I could not get the above working, so here's my attempt in my `.vimrc` :)

`imap <expr> > getline('.')[col('.')-2] !~# '\s' ? '><Esc>bvwy/><CR>a</<Esc>p<Esc>bba' : '>'`

> it's a conditional mapping which ignores html-expansion if there's characters preceeding `>` (for example: `if foo > 3` gets ignored)

What I like about this mapping is that it's filetype-agnostic (which is handy in case of writing html inside a js-file e.g.)