# Navigating HTML tags in Vim

Tags: html, vim

I would like to be able to navigate through HTML tag by tag. Is there a way I can move from HTML tag to tag. (i.e. `*<div>hi</div><div>bye</div>` ---> `<div>hi</div>*<div>bye</div>`
I know about `cit` and `cat`, which is why I would imagine this is possible. Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jump to matching XML tags in Vim](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500989/jump-to-matching-xml-tags-in-vim)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The `matchit.vim` macro gets you most of the way there, allowing you to move to a closing tag with `%` as you would matching parens or braces.  It's included in many Vim distributions including the standard download, but often not enabled by default.

http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=39

Comment: Thanks! It's not excactly what I had wanted, but It's helping a lot.

Comment: Thanks! Totally didn't know that. Super easy to enable!

Comment: this one works without doing anything on neovim,  thanks!

Answer (score 189):

You can jump between tags using visual operators, in example:

1. Place the cursor on the tag.
2. Enter visual mode by pressing <kbd>v</kbd>.
3. Select the outer tag block by pressing <kbd>a</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> or <kbd>i</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> for inner tag block.

Your cursor should jump forward to the matching closing html/xml tag. To jump backwards from closing tag, press <kbd>o</kbd> or <kbd>O</kbd> to jump to opposite tag.

Now you can either exit visual by pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd>, change it by <kbd>c</kbd> or copy by <kbd>y</kbd>.

---

To record that action into register, press <kbd>qq</kbd> to start recording, perform tag jump as above (including <kbd>Esc</kbd>), press <kbd>q</kbd> to finish. Then to invoke jump, press <kbd>@q</kbd> (to repeat, hit `@@`).

---

See more help at `:help visual-operators` or `:help v_it`:

> <kbd>at</kbd>      a `<tag> </tag>` block (with tags)
>
> <kbd>it</kbd>      inner `<tag> </tag>` block

---

Alternatively use plugin such as [matchit.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=39) (See: [Using % in languages without curly braces](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/126/using-in-languages-without-curly-braces)).

---

See also:

- [How to jump between matching HTML/XML tags?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/780/467) at Vim SE
- [Jump to matching XML tags in Vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500989/jump-to-matching-xml-tags-in-vim) at stackoverflow SE
- [How can I find the close html tag quickly in vim?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4116362/how-can-i-find-the-close-html-tag-quickly-in-vim) at stackoverflow SE
- [How to navigate between begin and end html tag?](https://superuser.com/questions/189815/vim-how-to-navigate-between-begin-and-end-html-tag) at superuser SE
- [VIM jump from one xml tag to the closing one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38187/vim-jump-from-one-xml-tag-to-the-closing-one) at Unix SE
- [How can I select an html tag's content in Vim?](https://superuser.com/questions/182355/how-can-i-select-an-html-tags-content-in-vim) at superuser SE

Comment: Super good explanation thanks! Plus as a French I will never forget this motion any more.. "vat" "vit" is phonetically identical as "vas vite", which literaly means "go fast" :p

Answer (score -5):

Press `F`+`>`, then `;` or `,` to move around. When you're got there, press **a** (lowercase) to go to insert mode after cursor.