# Navigate to end of current html tag in vim?

Tags: c++, html, vim

Given the following C++ code:

```
void main
{
    // Cursor is on this line
    foobar();
    ...
    // End of main
}
```

If my cursor is at the indicated line, I can type `]}` and it will take me to the closing brace.

Given the following html

```
<body>
    <!-- Cursor is on this line -->
    <p>some text</p>
    <p>more text</p>
</body>
```

If my cursor is at the indicated line, what equivalent keys can I hit to go to the closing of the `body` tag?

I know that I could move the cursor up to the opening `body` tag then use `%` to jump to the closing tag, but sometimes my cursor is several pages down into `body` and I just want to go to the end!

Comment: Please see SO question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4116362/how-can-i-find-the-close-html-tag-quickly-in-vim

Comment: @AbhijeetKasurde That question is related, but still different. This is about jumping to the ending tag when you are *inside* the tag, not at the top of it.

Answer (score 4):

There is probably a better way, but I usually use `vat` to select the tag, repeat `at` until I have the tag I want, then press `<Esc>` to leave visual mode. Then either `%` will work after leaving visual mode, or `o` in visual mode, to jump to the other side of the tag if needed.

Answer (score 0):

In normal mode you can also do `/<\/bo`

That should do it. But I don't know if it's faster than what the others have suggested.