# How to jump to beginning of Tag in HTML vim which has long html content

Tags: vim

Following is code

```
<p>
Some Content
Some Content

My Cursor is here

Some Content
Some Content
</p>
```

How do I directly Jump to beginning of Tag `<p>` or `</p>`

`%` command needs your cursor to be on tag, I tried other based on `10G`. I cant expect number to visible all time.

I think there might be some smarter way to do this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jump to matching XML tags in Vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500989/jump-to-matching-xml-tags-in-vim)

Comment: % is working, But I want to jump from inside to the tag enclosing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using key sequence <kbd>v</kbd><kbd>a</kbd><kbd>t</kbd><kbd>o</kbd><kbd>ESC</kbd> will do it.

Check out the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10881471/5039312

Comment: I see this is working. `o` what is the purpose of this

Comment: Also, I still feel this is a long step. I would prefer something more shorter. though I can setup a map using your answer. Is there any built in stuff??

Comment: @AbibullahRahamathulah I don't think there's anything shorter, mappings are made for this

Comment: From the linked answer: once you've got your selection you can toggle between the top and bottom with `o`

Answer (score 0):

If you’re open to using a plugin, I use this: https://github.com/tmhedberg/matchit